# BindingSource And ComboBox: Combobox Binded on another Source

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, combobox, bindingsource

I would like to make Something in my form.
I have a Binding source binded on Linq to Sql Class. The class Workorder contains one field Site. I would like to display The combobox with all the site, but selected on the site form my workorder.

I'm clear?

Julien

Answer (score 0):

I found the way through the Databindings component that allow to add more than one source to the TextBox.

Ju